# C# Changing Column Headers in DataGridView

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

I've got a datagridview in my project, which is populated from a SQL database with the following code:

```
 public cToDoList(string paramUser, DateTime paramDueDate)
    {
        string sqlStat = "SELECT * FROM tblDiary " +
                         "WHERE DiaryUserFor = @User " +
                         "AND DiaryDueDate <= @DueDate;";
        SqlCommand sqlCom = new SqlCommand(sqlStat);
        sqlCom.Parameters.Add("@User", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        sqlCom.Parameters.Add("@DueDate", SqlDbType.Date);
        sqlCom.Parameters["@User"].Value = paramUser;
        sqlCom.Parameters["@DueDate"].Value = paramDueDate.Date;

        cSqlQuery sqlQ = new cSqlQuery(sqlCom, "table");
        this.cTable = sqlQ.cQueryResults;
    }
```

The above code works fine and the datagridview is populated, however the column headers are the field names from the SQL database which aren't very user friendly.

I've tried a couple of things to try and change the default column names, but nothing isworking.  So far I've tried -

```
dataToDoList.Columns[0].Name = "TEST1";

dataToDoList.Columns["DiaryCompletedDate"].Name = "TEST2";
```

But neither do anything.

Can anyone tell me how to change column header names in a datagridview please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are the exact Columns you need..?

`Replace the SELECT * with`

```
 SELECT ColumnName AS 'TEST1', ColumnName2 AS 'TEST2' FROM ...etc
```

Comment: In hindsight Aliases was the best solution for my app.  Thank you.

Comment: Sounds good Pete Glad that many of us here could point you in the right direction

Answer (score 3):

Try [DataGridViewColumn.HeaderText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.headertext.aspx) & [AutoGenerateColumns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autogeneratecolumns.aspx) (MSDN)

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 2):

You want `Column.HeaderText`, not `Column.Name`.

---

Alternatively, set column properties using the visual designer, and in the form constructor set

```
dataToDoList.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy way would be to explicitly name the columns you want in the SQL.

Ie. replace `select *` (which you probably shouldn't use anyway) with `select DiaryCompletedDate [TEST1], OtherColumn [TEST2], ..` etc

Answer (score 1):

while data-binding the grid you can change the HeaderText like this

```
this.dataGridView1.Columns["ResourceValue"].HeaderText = Helper.getlocalStringResource("Xinga.LocalStrings.ColumnHeader.ResourceValue");
```